# How to forbid a certain character from starting a line of output text? Specifically concerning Tibetan text

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, newunicodechar, tibetan

I am typesetting texts in Tibetan, and I am trying to replicate a traditional Tibetan typesetting convention (they mostly used handwritten manuscripts or xylographs/wood-block prints).  There is a rule that a *shad* (།), which is the most common punctuation mark, can never start a new line.  It seems that this convention may have been worked into the `polyglossia` package code, because the mistake is rather rare. However, it does happen. What do I add to my code so that a new line never starts with a *shad*?

MWE, with two *shad* that begin a line in red:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[margin=3in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
   \setmainlanguage{tibetan}
   \newfontfamily\tibetanfont{Jomolhari}
   
\begin{document}

\Large
ཐེག་པ་ཆེན་པོའི་ཚུལ་ལ་འཇུག་པ་མདོ་ཙམ་བརྗོད་པ། གང་ཟག་གང་དག་འཁོར་བའི་རྒྱ་མཚོ་ལས་ཐར་བར་འདོད་ཅིང་། 
བླ་ན་མེད་པའི་བྱང་ཆུབ་བསྒྲུབ་པར་འདོད་པ་རྣམས་ཀྱིས། ཐོག་མར་ཁོ་ནར་ཉོན་མོངས་པ་རྣམས་ཀྱི་མཚན་ཉིད་ལ་བརྟགས་པར་རིགས་སོ། 
{\color{red}།}གང་གི་ཕྱིར་ཉོན་མོངས་པ་རྣམས་ཀྱིས་བཅིངས་ཏེ། འགྲོ་བ་རྣམས་འཁོར་བའི་རྒྱ་མཚོར་འཁྱམས་སོ། 
།ཞེས་བཀའ་སྤྱི་ལས་གྲགས་པའི་ཕྱིར་རོ། །དེའི་འོག་ཏུ་དེ་རྣམས་ཀྱི་གཉེན་པོར་གྱུར་པའི་ལམ་གྱི་མཆོག ཉོན་མོངས་པ་ཐམས་ཅད་སྤངས་པར་གདོན་མི་ཟའོ། 
{\color{red}།}གཞན་ཡང་གང་ཞིག་གིས་ཤེས་བྱ་རྣམས་ལ་རྣམ་པར་དབྱེ་བ་གྲངས་ལས་འདས་པ་ཞིག་ཏུ་རྣམ་པར་ཕྱེ་སྟེ། 
དེ་རྣམས་ལ་ཆོས་བདག་མེད་པར་རྟོགས་པར་བྱས་ན། དེ་དག་ཐམས་ཅད་ཀྱིས་ཀྱང་ཉོན་མོངས་པ་སྤོང་བར་འགྱུར་བ་གདོན་མི་ཟའོ།

\end{document}
```

UPDATE

I have tried egreg's suggestion (see answer below) of using the `newunicodechar` package to modify the way a *shad* is printed.  When it sees a *shad*, the code prompts latex to check if there is any blank space before it, and if there is, it replaces this blank space with a non-line-breaking space.  We tried this approach because it seems the problem of a *shad* beginning a new line only happens when the *shad* comes after a space.  This works for egreg, but when I compile the exact same code I get the below result, with spaces before *shad*s where there shouldn't be any.  The first *shad*, however, is properly directly adjacent to the preceding character.  I am compiling the exact same code as egreg, so it seems that the problem must lie in a difference between our latex setups.

[image: compare this result, using that exact same code, with that of egreg in the below answer]

Comment: You have a space before the two colored occurrences of a shad: is it expected to be preceded by a space?

Comment: @egreg Good catch. If there **is** really supposed to be a space there that cannot end a line, it should be a non-breaking space, `~`. (I can’t read Tibetan and have no idea whether or not that would be the case.)

Comment: It seems the shad only starts a line for me if it comes after a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can set things up so that the shad removes a blank space preceding it and substitutes it with a nonbreaking space.

This won't work if you want to color it; in that case, remember to have `~` in front of it.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[margin=3in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainlanguage{tibetan}
\newfontface\tibetanfont{Jomolhari-Regular.ttf}
\newunicodechar{།}{\ifdim\lastskip>0pt\unskip\nobreakspace\fi །}

\begin{document}

\Large
ཐེག་པ་ཆེན་པོའི་ཚུལ་ལ་འཇུག་པ་མདོ་ཙམ་བརྗོད་པ། གང་ཟག་གང་དག་འཁོར་བའི་རྒྱ་མཚོ་ལས་ཐར་བར་འདོད་ཅིང་། 
བླ་ན་མེད་པའི་བྱང་ཆུབ་བསྒྲུབ་པར་འདོད་པ་རྣམས་ཀྱིས། ཐོག་མར་ཁོ་ནར་ཉོན་མོངས་པ་རྣམས་ཀྱི་མཚན་ཉིད་ལ་བརྟགས་པར་རིགས་སོ།
།གང་གི་ཕྱིར་ཉོན་མོངས་པ་རྣམས་ཀྱིས་བཅིངས་ཏེ། འགྲོ་བ་རྣམས་འཁོར་བའི་རྒྱ་མཚོར་འཁྱམས་སོ། 
།ཞེས་བཀའ་སྤྱི་ལས་གྲགས་པའི་ཕྱིར་རོ། །དེའི་འོག་ཏུ་དེ་རྣམས་ཀྱི་གཉེན་པོར་གྱུར་པའི་ལམ་གྱི་མཆོག ཉོན་མོངས་པ་ཐམས་ཅད་སྤངས་པར་གདོན་མི་ཟའོ། 
།གཞན་ཡང་གང་ཞིག་གིས་ཤེས་བྱ་རྣམས་ལ་རྣམ་པར་དབྱེ་བ་གྲངས་ལས་འདས་པ་ཞིག་ཏུ་རྣམ་པར་ཕྱེ་སྟེ། 
དེ་རྣམས་ལ་ཆོས་བདག་མེད་པར་རྟོགས་པར་བྱས་ན། དེ་དག་ཐམས་ཅད་ཀྱིས་ཀྱང་ཉོན་མོངས་པ་སྤོང་བར་འགྱུར་བ་གདོན་མི་ཟའོ།

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that it added spaces in front of the shads that originally didn't have spaces in front of them.  It seems that \lastskip is somehow reading in a value greater than zero when it should be reading zero, i.e. when there is no space preceding.

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I seem to have pasted the wrong picture.

Comment: I see.  I notice that you changed the \newfontfamily command to \newfontface and the name of the font to "Jomolhari-Regular.ttf" as opposed to just "Jomolhari."  I can't do this, I get a fontspec error: "The font `Jomolhari-Regular' cannot be found," even though I do have this font on my computer.  When I do typeset it using my simply Jomolhari as the font I get the unwanted spaces before the shads, as in the first picture you pasted.  So the problem seems to be related to the Tibetan font.  Not sure how to get fontspec to find Jomolhari-Regular.ttf.

Comment: @Paul The font name change is due to the fact I have downloaded it from Google, but I'm not wanting to install it as a system font; if you have it in the system, calling it as you do should be equivalent. I can't see how the code can yield spaces where there aren't.

Comment: hmmmm. I was able to get it to use "Jomolhari Regular" by taking off the suffix .ttf. I still have spaces before shads where there shouldn't be, but strangely, not before the first shad in the text. Every other shad has a space before it.   I wonder what is different between your setup and mine that yours comes out right.  And what you may have done to get the first result you posted, which seems to be the same as I keep getting.

Comment: @Paul In the removed picture I didn't have the conditional `\ifdim\lastskip=0pt`

Comment: I see. I notice that compiling in this way with other Tibetan texts (in addition to with my MWE modified with your code) that the first shad in the body of the text which comes after a letter comes out correctly, i.e. with no space between it and the preceding letter. But every other shad after that has a space before it, many times erroneously. Some such shads in the title, which is in the "center" environment, come out correctly as well.  I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Paul I don't know what to say. If a space appears, it *must* come from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I'll update this question if I ever figure it out.

Comment: egreg— just to confirm: when you say in your above comment that you didn't have the ```\ifdim\lastskip=0``` in the code for your first picture,  I'm assuming you mean ```\ifdim\lastskip>0```.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Paul Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: After playing around with it some more, I believe that the conditional ```\ifdim``` command is not processing for some reason.  So it is adding a non-breaking space before every *shad*.  What could be the reason that the ```\ifdim``` command isn't working?

Comment: @Paul I can't say: it *does* work for me.

Comment: Maybe I should post a new question specifically on this problem with the ```\ifdim``` command?

Comment: @Paul Are you typesetting the same exact code?

Comment: Yes.  To make sure I just now copied and pasted your MWE into a new file, and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my tibex.tex package, with some sed scripts to automate the punctuation typesetting of Tibetan. Sorry for it is for plain XeTeX only, cause I don't know how to programming LaTeX packages yet. It is available at https://gitee.com/gendun-jiangcuo/tibexpkg.git. Some examples is at https://gitee.com/gendun-jiangcuo/tibex.git. Most of the docs are in Chinese, sorry for that.